# Angular resolve promise and update existing scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-promise

I am trying to understand Angular's promises and scopes. Actually I implemented the directive bellow. The thing that I want to do is to receive images from server and store locally in order to cache them for next times. Also I want to show a spinner before the load of image is completed and show it after the completion. 
How can update variable newUrl into directive when completed all of these promises?
Do you have any idea?

My HTML code is:

```
 <div style="text-align: center;"
     cache-src         
     url="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c0/Aix_galericulata_(Male),_Richmond_Park,_UK_-_May_2013.jpg">
 </div>
```

My directive is:

```
.directive('cacheSrc', [function () {
return {
  restrict: 'A',
  scope: {
    url: '@'
  },
  controller: 'cacheSrcCtrl',
  template: '<img width="100%" ng-if="newUrl!=null" src="{{newUrl}}"><ion-spinner ng-if="newUrl==null" icon="spiral"></ion-spinner>',
};
  }])
```

And the controller of directive has the function bellow:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
  $scope.updateUrl = function (newUrl) {
    $scope.newUrl = newUrl;
  };

  var tmp = $scope.url;
  $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, 'SELECT * FROM images where url = (?)', [tmp])
    .then(function (result) {
      if (result.rows.length > 0) {
        $scope.exists = true;
        for (var i = 0; i < res.rows.length; i++) {
          var image = {
            id: res.rows.item(i).id,
            url: res.rows.item(i).url,
            uri: res.rows.item(i).uri
          };
          $scope.updateUrl(image.uri);
        }
      } else {
        $scope.exists = false;
        var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
        var uri = encodeURI(tmp);
        var uriSave = '';
        var fileURL = cordova.file.dataDirectory + uri;//'kaloudiaImages';// + getUUID();// + "DCIM/myFile";
        fileTransfer.download(
          uri, fileURL, function (entry) {
            uriSave = entry.toURL();
            KaloudiaDB.add(tmp, fileURL);
            $scope.newUrl = fileURL;
            $scope.updateUrl(fileURL);
          },
          function (error) {
            console.log("download error code" + error.code);
          },
          false, {
            headers: {
              // "Authorization": "Basic dGVzdHVzZXJuYW1lOnRlc3RwYXNzd29yZA=="
            }
          }
        ).then(function (data) {
          $scope.newUrl = fileURL;
        });
      }
    }, function (error) {
      $scope.statusMessage = "Error on saving: " + error.message;
    })
    .then(function (data) {
      $scope.$apply(function () {
        $scope.newUrl = fileURL;
      });
    });
});
```

Comment: And your specific question is...?

Comment: How can update variable newUrl into directive when completed all of these promises?